# Why is my ExtJS datagrid populating as empty?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datagrid, extjs, grid

I am trying to make a proof of concept ExtJS datagrid en route to moving to a server-based store. At present my code is as follows:

```
var arrayData = [
  ['', 'Held', '', '', 'abc', '', '100.00', '0.00', 'Internal Approval'],
  /* 11 similar rows deleted for sanitization's sake */
  /* I've tried with and without quotes around the monetary amounts. */
  ];

var nameRecord = Ext.data.Record.create([
  {name: 'approved_date', mapping: 1},
  {name: 'approval_status', mapping: 2},
  {name: 'approval_id', mapping: 3},
  {name: 'reference_id', mapping: 4},
  {name: 'manufacturer_distributor_name', mapping: 5},
  {name: 'shipping_authorization_number', mapping: 6},
  {name: 'purchase_order_number', mapping: 7},
  {name: 'original_amount', mapping: 8},
  {name: 'open_amount', mapping: 9},
  {name: 'requestor', mapping: 10}
  ]);

var arrayReader = new Ext.data.ArrayReader({}, nameRecord);

var memoryProxy = new Ext.data.MemoryProxy(arrayData);

var store = new Ext.data.Store({
  reader: arrayReader,
  proxy: memoryProxy
  });

var columnModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
  {
  header: 'Approved Date',
  sortable: true,

  dataIndex: 'approved_date'
  },
  {
  header: 'Approval Status',
  sortable: true,
  dataIndex: 'approval_status'
  },
  {
  header: 'Approval ID',
  sortable: true,
  dataIndex: 'approval_id'
  },
  {
  header: 'Reference ID',
  sortable: true,
  dataIndex: 'reference_id'
  },
  {
  header: 'Manufacturer / Distributor Name',
  sortable: true,
  dataIndex: 'manufacturer_distributor_name'
  },
  {
  header: 'Shipping Authorization Number',
  sortable: true,
  dataIndex: 'shipping_authorization_number'
  },
  {
  header: 'Purchase Order Number',
  sortable: true,
  dataIndex: 'purchase_order_number'
  },
  {
  header: 'Original Amount',
  sortable: true,
  dataIndex: 'original_amount'
  },
  {
  header: 'Open Amount',
  sortable: true,
  dataIndex: 'open_amount',
  },
  {
  header: 'Requestor',
  sortable: true,
  dataIndex: 'requestor'
  }]);

var gridView = new Ext.grid.GridView();

var selectionModel = new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
  singleSelect: true
  });

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
  title: 'Approvals',
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  height: 500,
  width: 700,
  store: store,
  view: gridView,
  colModel: columnModel,
  selModel: selectionModel
  });
```

This is intended to closely follow the "Hello world"-level grid example on pp. 159-161 in Jesus Garcia's *ExtJS in Action*. As it stands, my code populates column names with a blank white area; that is, it displays the column names and a blank white area on FF/Chrome, and doesn't seem to display anything on IE6-8. In Chrome, the JavaScript console does not show any error messages, or other logged information.

Any suggestions about what is wrong with my code or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE-6-8 may  not be liking the dangling comma at `dataIndex: 'open_amount',` (and any other syntax errors that FF/Chrome would forgive)

Can you post a screenshot of what you are seeing in FF/Chrome?

Your code can be simplified quite a bit. e.g. Simply use [ArrayStore](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.ArrayStore) instead of reader,proxy,record,store combination

EDIT-

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    title: 'Approvals',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 500,
    width: 700,
    store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
      idIndex:0,
      fields: ['approved_date', 'approval_status',{name:'approval_id', type:'int'}] //specify other fields here
    }),
    cm:new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
      defaults:{
        sortable:true,
        width:200
      },
      columns:[{
       header:'Approval Date',
       dataIndex:'approved_date'
      },{
        header:'Approval Status',
        dataIndex:'approval_status'
      },{
        header:'Approval ID',
        dataIndex:'approval_id'
      }]                    
    })
});

var myData=[
  ['01/01/11','Held', 1],
  ['02/02/11','Approved', 2]
]

grid.getStore().loadData(myData);
```

Comment: I know my code isn't very DRY; I was aiming for a proof of concept done exactly the way the book did it. Thanks for noticing the unnecessary comma; now IE8 renders like Chrome and Firefox while IE6-7 briefly display something very similar-looking, but then say that the network connection was aborted, and display a generic error page.

Comment: Can you try the sample code I have above or in your code, do a store.load() after defining the store.

Comment: Thank you! It is now up and running and I am up and tinkering. Thanks!